# Google Adsense Ads not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, adsense

Im trying to implement google adsense ads and they aren't showing up, but when I inspect the area they are suppose to be it looks like they are there.  Im working in a rails 5 app and I am using turbolinks, which Ive seen may cause issues.  Heres the code in my project:

```
<div class: 'recipe-card-link'>
                <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
                <ins class="adsbygoogle"
                     style="display:block"
                     data-ad-format="fluid"
                     data-ad-layout="image-top"
                     data-ad-layout-key="-90+2e-hl+fr+q4"
                     data-ad-client="ca-pub-****************"
                     data-ad-slot="8061638025"></ins>
                <script>
                     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
                </script>
            </div>
```

When I inspect the item it has a bunch of   etc inputs and looks like it called the script and put everything there but nothing shows up.  Its just a white space.

EDIT: Attached an image of what it shows when I inpsect (since I cant copy all of it)

[image: Element Inspected after load]

Comment: Are you sure that your Adsense account is already approved? ...It could take a while.

Comment: It says approved in the account settings for adsense.  The script loads the stuff so it looks like its doing what its suppose to, just not displaying anything

Answer (score 0):

1.- First, try changing:

*script async* to *script async='async'*

2.- Then use the following JS to run adsense.

```
<script>
//<![CDATA[
  (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
    google_ad_client: "ca-pub-YOURID",
    enable_page_level_ads: true
  });
//]]>
</script>
```